Fsck exited with status code 1
I use Ubuntu 22.04.
The rootfile system requires manual fsck  occurs most frequently.
I tried"fsck -yf/dev/sda2 then exit
Sometimes it works, but then I see:
fsck exited with status code 1.

And the system doesn't react after that. I have attached this image.


I'll suggest forget about file-system checks; I'd check the drive health... as if you're using a failing drive; you're wasting whatever life it has left trying to resolve symptoms but not even addressing your issue.  Use your drive's SMART capabilities. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  Keep any remaining life left for getting data back before it's too late.

This question is similar to: Root filesystem requires manual fsck, normal solutions not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is it the exit status specifically that you are asking about - from man fsck (or man fsck.ext4 for example) it's just telling you that errors were corrected
